# How to run simple Qt application with out net support in kernel?

Tags: user-interface, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux, qtembedded

I have a simple qt application for arm based board, build with yocto and I am trying to run that in target. without net support in linux I am getting error like below.

```
root@ek:~# mainwindow
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
QWSSocket::connectToLocalFile could not connect:: Function not implemented
No Qt for Embedded Linux server appears to be running.
If you want to run this program as a server,
add the "-qws" command-line option.
root@ek:~# mainwindow -qws
QWSServerSocket::init: Function not implemented
QWSServerSocket: unable to create socket.
QWSServerPrivate::initServer: server socket not listening: Function not implemented
Failed to bind to /tmp/qtembedded-0/QtEmbedded-0
Aborted
root@ek:~#
```

Is there any way (configuring) to build qt application without using network framework of kernel. I wanted very minimal kernel image for my tiny device.

Comment: Considering the size of Qt itself, it makes more sense to enable some basic network support on the kernel side. It will save you plenty of trouble later at an expense of few tens of kilobytes.

Comment: You won't be able to use QWS without networking, I guess

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld: We are using the same (with -embedded arm). even it is expecting socket.